# Error: react-navigation_v1.x.x/CONTRIBUTING.md: Unexpected file name

Tags: flowtype, flow-typed

What's I'm doing wrong?

My .flowconfig

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/.*
.*/dist/.*

[include]

[libs]

[lints]

[options]
platform=browser
module.file_ext=.jsx

[strict]
```

When I try to install type defs..

```
npx flow-typed install
```

I receive the error

```
❯ npx flow-typed install
• Found 66 dependencies in package.json to install libdefs for. 
Searching...
UNCAUGHT ERROR: Error: react-navigation_v1.x.x/CONTRIBUTING.md: 
Unexpected file name. This directory can only contain test files or a 
libdef file named `react-navigation_v1.x.x.js`.
     at validationError ( ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there was a change in `flow-typed` internals which now allows for `.md` files to be part of the definitions, but this requires you to upgrade to `flow-typed` v2.4+. Try upgrading your `flow-typed` version and see if it helps.

Comment: I have the same problem and have upgraded to flow-typed@2.4.0 but I am still getting the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't some mismatch between your locally installed version vs a globally installed `flow-typed`?